# How can I debug a JS Unit Test with Karma & Jasmine in Intellij or Webstorm

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intellij-idea, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to debug my JS unit tests written in Jasmine and run by Karma. How can I put a breakpoint in my tests in Intellij when running my tests? And how can I execute a single test?

Here's my Intellij's Run config for executing Karma Tests

[image: Here's my Intellij's Karma TEST Run Config]

Here's my example unit test

```
import {
    RouterTestingModule
} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {
    async,
    TestBed,
    ComponentFixture
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { provideRoutes, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/navbar/navbar.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'as-test-cmp',
    template: '<div class="title">Hello test</div>'
})
class TestRouterComponent {
}

let config: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: TestRouterComponent
    }
];

describe('AppComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                TestRouterComponent,
                AppComponent,
                NavbarComponent
            ],
            imports: [ RouterTestingModule, RouterModule ],
            providers: [ provideRoutes(config) ]
        });
    });

    it('should have title Hello world', async(() => {
        TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
            let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
            fixture.detectChanges();

            let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
            expect(compiled).toBeDefined();
            // TODO: find a way to compile the routed component
            // expect(compiled.querySelector('div.title')).toMatch('Hello world');
        });
    }));
});
```

Here's my karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    var gulpConfig = require('../gulp/config')();

    /**
     * List of npm packages that imported via `import` syntax
     */
    var dependencies = [
        '@angular',
        'lodash',
        'rxjs',
        'moment'
    ];

    var configuration = {
        basePath: '../../',

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

        preprocessors: {},

        // Generate json used for remap-istanbul
        coverageReporter: {
            dir: 'report/',
            reporters: [
                {type: 'json', subdir: 'report-json'}
            ]
        },

        files: [
            'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
            'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'node_modules/moment/moment.js'
        ],

        // proxied base paths
        proxies: {
            // required for component assests fetched by Angular's compiler
            "/src/": "/base/src/",
            "/app/": "/base/src/app/",
            "/node_modules/": "/base/node_modules/"
        },

        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true
    };

    configuration.preprocessors[gulpConfig.tmpApp + '**/!(*.spec)+(.js)'] = ['coverage'];
    configuration.preprocessors[gulpConfig.tmpApp + '**/*.js'] = ['sourcemap'];
    configuration.preprocessors[gulpConfig.tmpTest + '**/*.js'] = ['sourcemap'];

    var files = [
        gulpConfig.tmpTest + 'test-helpers/global/**/*.js',
        gulpConfig.src + 'systemjs.conf.js',
        'config/test/karma-test-shim.js',
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.tmpApp + '**/*.js', {included: false}),
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.tmpTest + 'test-helpers/*.js', {included: false}),
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.app + '**/*.html', {included: false}),
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.app + '**/*.css', {included: false}),
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.app + '**/*.ts', {included: false, watched: false}),
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.tmpApp + '**/*.js.map', {included: false, watched: false})
    ];

    configuration.files = configuration.files.concat(files);

    dependencies.forEach(function (key) {
        configuration.files.push({
            pattern: 'node_modules/' + key + '/**/*.js',
            included: false,
            watched: false
        });
    });

    if (process.env.APPVEYOR) {
        configuration.browsers = ['IE'];
        configuration.singleRun = true;
        configuration.browserNoActivityTimeout = 90000; // Note: default value (10000) is not enough
    }

    config.set(configuration);

    // Helpers
    function createFilePattern(path, config) {
        config.pattern = path;
        return config;
    }
}
module.exports = function (config) {
    var gulpConfig = require('../gulp/config')();

    /**
     * List of npm packages that imported via `import` syntax
     */
    var dependencies = [
        '@angular',
        'lodash',
        'rxjs',
        'moment'
    ];

    var configuration = {
        basePath: '../../',

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

        preprocessors: {},

        // Generate json used for remap-istanbul
        coverageReporter: {
            dir: 'report/',
            reporters: [
                {type: 'json', subdir: 'report-json'}
            ]
        },

        files: [
            'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
            'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'node_modules/moment/moment.js'
        ],

        // proxied base paths
        proxies: {
            // required for component assests fetched by Angular's compiler
            "/src/": "/base/src/",
            "/app/": "/base/src/app/",
            "/node_modules/": "/base/node_modules/"
        },

        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true
    };

    configuration.preprocessors[gulpConfig.tmpApp + '**/!(*.spec)+(.js)'] = ['coverage'];
    configuration.preprocessors[gulpConfig.tmpApp + '**/*.js'] = ['sourcemap'];
    configuration.preprocessors[gulpConfig.tmpTest + '**/*.js'] = ['sourcemap'];

    var files = [
        gulpConfig.tmpTest + 'test-helpers/global/**/*.js',
        gulpConfig.src + 'systemjs.conf.js',
        'config/test/karma-test-shim.js',
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.tmpApp + '**/*.js', {included: false}),
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.tmpTest + 'test-helpers/*.js', {included: false}),
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.app + '**/*.html', {included: false}),
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.app + '**/*.css', {included: false}),
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.app + '**/*.ts', {included: false, watched: false}),
        createFilePattern(gulpConfig.tmpApp + '**/*.js.map', {included: false, watched: false})
    ];

    configuration.files = configuration.files.concat(files);

    dependencies.forEach(function (key) {
        configuration.files.push({
            pattern: 'node_modules/' + key + '/**/*.js',
            included: false,
            watched: false
        });
    });

    if (process.env.APPVEYOR) {
        configuration.browsers = ['IE'];
        configuration.singleRun = true;
        configuration.browserNoActivityTimeout = 90000; // Note: default value (10000) is not enough
    }

    config.set(configuration);

    // Helpers
    function createFilePattern(path, config) {
        config.pattern = path;
        return config;
    }
}
```

Comment: to execute a single test you should use "fit" instead of "it". Currently that is the only way because karma loads entire file. If you want to run only one suite then you can use "fdescribe".

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it? I am facing exactly the same problems and everything I tried did not work. It seems a normal expectation to be able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is right, but before that you have to install chrome extension [Jetbrains IDE support plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji), and then you can debug in your WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug on your browser. Just click on the DEBUG button, find your class and add a breakpoint wherever you want. To run it again, just refresh the page.

Comment: I know how to do that when Karma executes. I want to be able to debug in my IDE just like I can with other languages.